# How to get One value from an array (protractor)?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, protractor

Is it possible to get One value from an array such as:

```
Array
(
    [id] = 100917
    [sid] = SM0ddb860df74148f19f57b314bfc80b39
    [date_created] = 2016-02-10 12:04:08
    [date_updated] = 2016-02-10 12:04:08
    [date_sent] = 
    [to] = +996559138088
    [from] = +15674434357
    [body] = Confirmation code: 75ba76
    [status] = queued
    [direction] = outbound-api
    [price] = 
    [price_unit] = USD
)
```

I need somehow to get a value of "75ba76" (in confirmation code string) using:

[to] = +996559138088

When i try to select it, i see:

http://prntscr.com/a1cngn

Any ideas?..
Thanks.

Comment: So you want to get the value of [body] by accessing [to]? I don't get it...

Comment: [body] is a temporary meaning that sent to [to].
so, i need to get somehow this [body] to use it in the next test.

Comment: the flow is the next;
- user enter his mobile phone [to] and click «forget pass?».
- then i have to open new tab in browser with url where this Array contains.
- as there are many similar arrays, i have to find user’s mobile phone [to] and get his temporary code [body].. after what i have to enter this [body] to the new field (in new url).
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a strong brainstorm i solved the problem using the next code. It's maybe seems to be huge, but it works great!

```
    it("get temp password", function () {        
    browser.get("http://api.test.yalla.ng/sms.php?db=stena_kg");

    var preElement = element.all(by.css('pre'));
    var matchPhone =  browser.params.phones.matchPhone;
    var matchPass;

    var elementIndex = 0;
    parseNextElement();

    function parseNextElement() {
        preElement.get(elementIndex).getText().then(function (text) {
            parseElementData(text);
            if(!matchPass){
                elementIndex++;
                parseNextElement();
            }else{
                onMatch();
            }
        });
    }

    function parseElementData(data){
        var dataArr = data.split("\n");
        var phoneTxt = "";
        var passTxt = "";

        for(var i = 0; i<dataArr.length; i++){
            var str = dataArr[i];
            var splitStr = str.split(" ");
            if(str.match(/\[to\]/)){
                phoneTxt = splitStr[splitStr.length - 1];
            }
            if(str.match(/\[body\]/)){
                passTxt = splitStr[splitStr.length - 1];
            }
        }

        console.log(phoneTxt, passTxt);

        if(phoneTxt == matchPhone){
            matchPass = passTxt;
        }
    }

    function onMatch(){
        console.log("COMPLETE!!!", matchPass);
    }

}, 600000);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string and array operations to get the value that you need, as text in html elements are stored as strings by default. [`filter()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) function can be used to get the `<pre>` element that has the number you specify in `arrString` variable below. Here's how -

```
var arrString = "[to] = +996559138088";
var reqValue;
element.all(by.css('pre')).filter(function(ele){
    return ele.getText().then(function(str){
        return str.search(arrString) > -1;
    });
}).getText().then(function(val){ //returns array as a string
    reqValue = val.split('\n').filter(function(eachEle){return eachEle.search(/body/i)>-1}).toString().split(' ').pop();
    //reqValue holds the data that you require
});
```

Though code looks a little weird, it should do the job. Hope it helps.

Comment: @EkaterinaSidelnikova a question, your `pre` element has exactly the value that you have shown in the screenshot right? Can you tell me what you get when you perform `getText()` on the first `pre` element? Thanks